# Removing non-numbers from a string in SPSS

Tags: string, replace, spss

Consider the following data:

[image: Sample data - numbers mixed with text]

As you can see, the values of the variable are inherently numeric, but include text in some of them. I have tried every permutation I could think of `do repeat...end repeat` to try and remove the non-numeric values and leave just the numbers, without success.

Is there some syntax that will do it?
Is there a function that checks whether a substr contains any of a set of characters? Then I could create a set that represents all the digits, loop through each character in the string, and if it is not in the set, replace it with a null.

Comment: If @horace_vr's answer solves your problem please select it as the solution (by clicking the V button on the left of the answer), you are also welcome to upvotie it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer on IBM support answers a somewhat similar question:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/removing-unwanted-characters-strings

You will have a lot more characters to search (the whole a-z, A-Z and probably some non-letter characters as well), but it should work.
You might also want to use the newer, `CHAR.INDEX` and `CHAR.REPLACE` functions, if you are using SPSS 223 or newer; see the official IBM SPSS documentation on them:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_transformation_expressions_string_functions.html

**Later Edit (after clarifications and suggestions from the OP:**

What you need to adjust in the IBM examples is 2 things:

1. hardcode the loop exit after k iterations (not when #I=0 - that will stop at the first character it does not find). In the below example, k is set to 100.
2. specify all characters you want to remove: a to z, space, quotation (as 2 consecutive  quotation signs), and so on; anything you think you might want to clean. Then this should work (and indeed stackoverflow, formatting does not seem to be working properly at the moment)

   COMPUTE x=LOWER(x).

   LOOP k=1 to CHAR.LENGTH(x).

   COMPUTE #I = CHAR.INDEX(X,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+, ''',1).

   IF #I > 0 X=CONCAT(CHAR.SUBSTR(X,1,#I-1), CHAR.SUBSTR(X,#I+1)).

   END LOOP.

   EXECUTE.

Comment: Running the following code (varname changed to x) produces the output that follows (apologies for the formatting. I followed rules on Comment Markdown, but it didn't work):

    compute x=lower(x).  
    string orig_x (a35).  
    compute orig_x=x.  
    execute.  

    LOOP .  
    COMPUTE #I = CHAR.INDEX(X,'abcdefghijklmnop+,',1) .  
    IF #I > 0 X=CONCAT(CHAR.SUBSTR(X,1,#I-1),CHAR.SUBSTR(X,#I+1)).  
    END LOOP IF #I=0 .  
    EXECUTE.  
  
  
3000  
ut 2500  
ss t 700  
1500 r r  
25000  
1900  
't w ut  t ut 2000  
250 s

Comment: To clarify: It is only deleting some of the characters listed. For example, About 2500 turns into ut 2500.

Comment: I added a few more details on what you need to change in IBM syntax; the code worked for me

Comment: I used LOOP k=1 to CHAR.LENGTH(x). but otherwise your code exactly. That did it!

Comment: indeed, nice one! did not think of it! I incorporated this in the answer; if the answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" answer, so others will know, in case they face the same problem